# Is there a way to call a jQuery plugin method after its been killed?

Tags: jquery

This plugin (https://github.com/markgoodyear/scrollup) has a kill method...

```
$.scrollUp.destroy();
```

Is there a way to reverse it, make it undead so to speak...j/k

I tried to attach it to a click function but it doesn't work!

```
$(function() {
            $('.ps-toolbar-close').click(function() {
                $.scrollUp({
                    scrollName: 'scrollUp', // Element ID
                    scrollDistance: 300, // Distance from top/bottom before showing element (px)
                    scrollFrom: 'top', // 'top' or 'bottom'
                    scrollSpeed: 3000, // Speed back to top (ms)
                    easingType: 'linear', // Scroll to top easing (see http://easings.net/)
                    animation: 'fade', // Fade, slide, none
                    animationInSpeed: 200, // Animation in speed (ms)
                    animationOutSpeed: 200, // Animation out speed (ms)
                    scrollText: 'Scroll to top', // Text for element, can contain HTML
                    scrollTitle: false, // Set a custom <a> title if required. Defaults to scrollText
                    scrollImg: true, // Set true to use image
                    activeOverlay: true, // Set CSS color to display scrollUp active point, e.g '#00FFFF'
                    zIndex: 2147483647 // Z-Index for the overlay
                });
            });
        });
```

Comment: No, you'll need to instantiate it again.

Comment: Your code seems correct. Re-initializing the scrollUp script will bring it "back from the dead". Perhaps the click event isn't firing at all?

Comment: Do you know how i'll instantiate it again?

Comment: Can a click not fire despite it being implemented correctly?

Comment: Maybe there is an error in your js code before the code of the click event and thus the execution stops there. Try to put some debug code in your click event, console.log(...) or alert(...)